# IOS 7 pushviewcontroller error

Tags: ios, pushviewcontroller

This snippet of IOS code used to work prior to IOS 7 to push a new window. It does not anymore

```
 ViewController *secondView = [[ViewController alloc]
                        initWithNibName:@"ViewController"bundle:nil];
   [[self navigationController] pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
```

Why doesn't this work anymore?

-------EDIT-----
This is the nav controller in didFinishLaunchingwWthOption

```
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
 self.launchViewController = [[LaunchViewController alloc] 
          initWithNibName:@"LaunchViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.LaunchViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

-------EDIT----------

The first time I invoke [self addNewView] the view does not appear, with no errors in the console or crashes, I added a button and if on the button press I invoke [self addNewView] the view appears, if I navigate with the back button, I have to tap back twice to return to the initial view. So the view is being created but not shown. Any hints on what could be the problem?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, so your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I have been using this snippet for years with no issue, so where could the problem be?

Comment: Check to make sure self.navigationController is not nil. Other than that, I can't see why it isn't working. What do you see anyway? Does nothing happen?

Comment: Could also be some code in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear in your ViewController is raising an exception.

Do you see any logs after you push?

Comment: Could also be that something is breaking the init of the view controller. Can you make sure secondView isn't nil?

Comment: please post the navigationcontroller object initialization code also

Comment: @San, logs are empty.

Comment: @hukir - How do I determine that secondView is not nil?

Comment: @hukir / Tori - secondView never be nil, because of its "alloc" nature. And even though nib name "ViewController" is not found, iOS will make sure to create a blank view and attaches with newly allocated view controller (secondView in this case).

Comment: I can sense only one obvious reason - [self navigationController] is nil. If self doesn't have navigationController attached, it will be nil always. @Tori NSLog(@"%@",[self navigationController]);

Comment: in that case the program will crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS, so [self navigationController] exists

Comment: @San: nav controller is null.

Comment: @Tori Then thats the problem! Create a navigation controller from storyboard or programmatically before presenting your class "ViewController"

Comment: There's a nav controller, I show the code in the question.

Comment: Could you please post your crash log, or what exactly is it saying? What exception is it? EXC_BAC_ACCESS or some other one? Try also setting up a global breakpoint on all exceptions... it will show you where the problem lies in 99% of cases.

Comment: @DominikHadl: There's no crash, no console output. Tapping the button to change the view does not switch to the new view. Tapping multiple times does not change the results.

Comment: @San Added another edit with more details on the behavior

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify tha bundle?

```
ViewController *secondView = [[ViewController alloc]
                    initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Comment: Tried that same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

check this:

UINavigationController *navi = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.launchViewController];

self.window.rootViewContro‌​ller = navi;

Answer (score 0):

There is mo navigationController.`window.rootViewController` should be a navigationController as your logic.